# Where is the documentation for the SObjectType value provider in Lightning Experience?

Tags: lightning, documentation

I searched a couple of days ago how can I get the current user Id in Lightning Experience without using an Apex controller, and found that I can use the following:

```
var userId = $A.get('$SObjectType.CurrentUser.Id');
```

The problem is that I can't find what else I can get with `$SObjectType`. [The documentation on Value Providers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_source.htm) only show `globalId`, `$Browser`, `$Label`, `$Locale` and `$Resource`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open idea to get sObjectType to Lightning - https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E4dRQAS.

Till that time the feature is implemented or documented, it may be safe to assume that it is not supported! What works may continue to work until it is broken.